# Заводить ли еще один класс для этой задачи?

Tags: java, ооп

Есть задача, написать программу, которая ищет пересечение множеств.
На вход подаются несколько множеств например

1. `(-i;-8.6][-8.5;-8.0][-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5][8.0;i)`
2. `(-i;-100][-90.5;-20.0][-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5]`
3. `(-i;-8.6][8.0;i)`
4. `[-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5][8.0;i)`

Я завел класс интервал. Это один интервал например `[-7.0;0.0]`
Завел класс множество- Массив интервалов `ArrayList`. Это несколько интервалов которые образуют 1 множество, например.

`(-i;-8.6][-8.5;-8.0][-7.0;0.0][1.1;7.5][8.0;i)`

Правильно ли заводить класс, который будет содержать все введенные множества? 
Или просто создать массив `ArrayList` содержащий все введенные множества. 
Задание тестовое, поэтому думаю это имеет значение.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что список данных является отдельной сущностью, со своим функционалом, реализованным в классе, то делайте отдельно. Если это просто данные, которые где-то используются, то и смысла выделять нет. А для оценки вашей реализации куда важнее, скорее всего, будет сам алгоритм пересечения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко - не стоит.

Если развернуто: в вашей задаче нет сущности набор множеств, с которым надо что-то такое делать. Ну например, если бы множество множеств составляли бы какую-то отдельную сущность - типа, как набор полигонов составляет какой-то рендер.

У вас такого нет, так что спокойно можно обойтись без такой сущности, следовательно и класса.

```
class Interval {
}

class Polygon {
   ArrayList<Interval> intervals;
   //возвращает пересечение с заданного полигона с текущим (this) полигоном
   //если нет пересечения возвращает null
   public Polygon intersect(Polygon polygon) {
      //blah-blah
   }
}
```

Comment: Тогда мне надо завести без класса ArrayList<Polygon> и оформить поиск его пересечения в виде функции?  Для поиска пересечения всех множеств нужно будет уметь находить пересечение 2х множеств. Где описать поиск пересечения 2х множеств- в классе Polygon или где?

Comment: см. апдейт ответа